# How to add cookie sessions on remember hidden dock state?

Tags: jquery, cookies

How would you add a cookie code to the code I currently have? I've been reading around, but I'm not the best with jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/k9vAJ/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visible = true;
    $("#docktoggle").on('click', function() { 
        $('.dock')
            .animate({ width: visible ? 0 : 980 }, "slow")
            .css({ display: visible ? "none" : "" })
            .css({ width: visible ? "none" : "100% !important" });
        visible = !visible;  
    });
});

$(function(){
    $(".img-swap").live('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
        } 
        else {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
});
```

Comment: How would I add cookie code... with the aim of achieving what?

Comment: @ Rory he just mentioned it, to remember the docked state that he is animating with that jQuery function defined above.. ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, have a cookie remember the state of the toggle (Hidden and/or Visible) on refresh and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

@user2041167:

You might want to use a jQuery plugin for that, I think that there is also some reference to this file. I know this because I have used it for jstree jQuery plugin as it comes with that packaged altogether. The plugin deals with interacting with the prototype defined for the cookie which ends up saved, if not mistaken into the browser.

```
            /**
             * Cookie plugin
             *
             * Copyright (c) 2006 Klaus Hartl (stilbuero.de)
             * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
             * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
             * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
             *
             */

            /**
             * Create a cookie with the given name and value and other optional parameters.
             *
             * @example $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
             * @desc Set the value of a cookie.
             * @example $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'jquery.com', secure: true });
             * @desc Create a cookie with all available options.
             * @example $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
             * @desc Create a session cookie.
             * @example $.cookie('the_cookie', null);
             * @desc Delete a cookie by passing null as value. Keep in mind that you have to use the same path and domain
             *       used when the cookie was set.
             *
             * @param String name The name of the cookie.
             * @param String value The value of the cookie.
             * @param Object options An object literal containing key/value pairs to provide optional cookie attributes.
             * @option Number|Date expires Either an integer specifying the expiration date from now on in days or a Date object.
             *                             If a negative value is specified (e.g. a date in the past), the cookie will be deleted.
             *                             If set to null or omitted, the cookie will be a session cookie and will not be retained
             *                             when the the browser exits.
             * @option String path The value of the path atribute of the cookie (default: path of page that created the cookie).
             * @option String domain The value of the domain attribute of the cookie (default: domain of page that created the cookie).
             * @option Boolean secure If true, the secure attribute of the cookie will be set and the cookie transmission will
             *                        require a secure protocol (like HTTPS).
             * @type undefined
             *
             * @name $.cookie
             * @cat Plugins/Cookie
             * @author Klaus Hartl/klaus.hartl@stilbuero.de
             */

            /**
             * Get the value of a cookie with the given name.
             *
             * @example $.cookie('the_cookie');
             * @desc Get the value of a cookie.
             *
             * @param String name The name of the cookie.
             * @return The value of the cookie.
             * @type String
             *
             * @name $.cookie
             * @cat Plugins/Cookie
             * @author Klaus Hartl/klaus.hartl@stilbuero.de
             */
            jQuery.cookie = function(name, value, options) {
                if (typeof value != 'undefined') { // name and value given, set cookie
                    options = options || {};
                    if (value === null) {
                        value = '';
                        options.expires = -1;
                    }
                    var expires = '';
                    if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
                        var date;
                        if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
                            date = new Date();
                            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                        } else {
                            date = options.expires;
                        }
                        expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString(); // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
                    }
                    // CAUTION: Needed to parenthesize options.path and options.domain
                    // in the following expressions, otherwise they evaluate to undefined
                    // in the packed version for some reason...
                    var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
                    var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
                    var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
                    document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
                } else { // only name given, get cookie
                    var cookieValue = null;
                    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return cookieValue;
                }
            };
```

Comment: maybe you should look into how to hook it up so that onchange state for that element, you trigger the check with the cookie from that js lib.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to read up on it, but I'm having a hard time understanding it, aha.

Comment: when you are defining your custom function, define a name and params for the cookie by calling the methods defined in the library.. this you can explore by using a plugin that works with jscookie and so on.. I normally tend to write those sort of hook ups after it remembers already the state.. those are my 2 cents worth ;)